# Magento - Configure City as Dropdown Option Shipping/Billing

Tags: magento, checkout, php

I'd like to know if you could help me with a little problem in a custom magento development.

I need to create a dropdown list for cities field in shipping.phtml and billing.phtml, like country/region, in this way, when i click a region, a list with cities would be displayed.

I've read many articles but anyone give me a concrete answer. The closest thing I've found is this article but it isn't complete yet. http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/2014/04/15/add-drop-down-for-city-in-address-form-part-1/

Is there a extension for this? Or a clear tutorial in which I can base me to create the table, js code (cityupdater.js or Ajax) and modify the necessary .phtml files

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for few days. I came up with a solution which suited my need. This is what I did.

**Goto app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

Find :
`<input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />`

and replace it with :

```
<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
     <option><?php echo $this->__('Please select city') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Mumbai') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Mumbai') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Thane') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Thane') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Navi Mumbai') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Navi Mumbai') ?></option>
</select>
```

Use the city names you want instead of Mumbai,Thane, Navi Mumbai. It worked for me.

Comment: Does that data was collected in DB without making any other code changes?